# Duplicate windows folders on different drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, storage, duplicate

I have seemingly redundant windows, users, program files, program files (x86) and programdata folders on two of my drives.
One drive is my bootdrive (C:) and the other is for storage only (D:). Both are SSDs. I am uncertain since when windows duplicated all the stuff. According to the drive management the C:\ drive is still the boot partition so I have no idea why it would mirror everything to the other drive without asking or telling me.

Does anyone know why this happened how it can be prevented and if there is an easy way to get rid of the duplicates?

[image: (diskmgmt.msc]

Comment: Please add a screen-shot of the disk management (diskmgmt.msc). BTW: Have you cloned the installation from the data SSD to the current system SSD in the past?

Comment: @Robert I added the picture to the question. No, I only installed windows once to the C: drive and have not changed anything since.

Comment: Which version of Windows? (Home/Pro, build number)? 120 Gb is IMO very small for a Windows boot partition.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC

Comment: Your disk structure is a real mess, with EFI and Recovery partitions scattered all over. Have you installed Windows several times, and each time on another disk? Or have you been running out of disk space and each time migrated everything to a new disk?

Comment: @harrymc As mentioned above I only ever installed it once onto the C: drive.

Comment: You might have installed Windows 10 on another disk than Windows 7?

Comment: @harrymc None of these disks contained any windows installation ever before

Comment: It seems like all of them were used for booting - were they cobbled together from several computers? Before putting some order in this, you will have to find which of the copies is the one used. Perhaps the simplest would be to look at the environment variable PATH and see which disk or disks are used. Also look at the modification dates of the folders (and their most recently used sub-folder) to find which ones are not being modified/used any more.

Comment: @harrymc No, all the drives were new before I installed anything on them. My best guess at this point is Windows update having done something horribly wrong.

Comment: Have you done the above checks?